# On loading the page, bootstrap-dismissible notice appears again after close

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, dismiss

I am using Bootstrap for displaying the notice

```
<div id="admin-notice" class="alert alert-dismissible alert-info fade in">
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
<p>Dummy Data</strong></a></p>
</div>
```

Above code, dismisses the notice, but when I reload the page, a notice appears again. Is there any way to view the notice only once?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Then you need to use cookie or local storage. Check this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32775/)** for local storage example and let me know.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('showstate') != 'shown'){
        $("#admin-notice").delay(2000).fadeIn();
        localStorage.setItem('showstate','shown')
    }

    $('.close').click(function(e) 
    {
    $('#admin-notice').fadeOut(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried using cookie. But I want to hide the notice only if the user has clicked "close" button. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Checked my fiddle. It is like that only.

Comment: If I reload the page without clicking on the close button, the notice is not shown

Comment: because you have closed it before and it gets saved in local storage. That's why it is not showing. As per your needs it will display only once until you clear the local storage of your browser.